# Kafka Streams Topic Retention Issue: Dynamic Topic Configurations and Unreleased Data

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I'm having an issue with a Kafka Streams application integrated with Spring Cloud Stream. The problem revolves around a specific topic that it continually increases in size and never releases data:

- ApplicationId-MergeUndoMyObject-KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000003-repartition

The retetion config for this topic is -1.

The implementation that generates this repartition is created by the following code:

```java
    @Bean
    public BiFunction<KStream<String, Undo>, KStream<String, MyObjectUpdate>, KStream<String, UndoMyObject>> mergeUndoWithMyObjectUpdate() {
        return (undo, myObjectUpdate) ->
                undo.selectKey((k, v) -> v.getMyObjectDesignator())
                        .join(myObjectUpdate.selectKey((k, v) -> (v.getMyObject() == null ? null : v.getMyObject().getDesignator())),
                                this::execute,
                                JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(3)),
                                StreamJoined.with(Serdes.String(),
                                        new JsonSerde<>(Undo.class),
                                        new JsonSerde<>(MyObjectUpdate.class)))
                        .filterNot((k, v) -> v == null)
                        .map((k, v) -> new KeyValue<>(v.getUndo().getId(), v))
                        .peek((k, v) -> {
                                    log.debug("Merged Undo with MyObjectUpdate -> {}, {}", v.getUndo().getId(), v.getAfterMyObject().getId());
                                    if (repository.getByKey(v.getUndo().getId()).isEmpty()) {
                                        undoStompController.send(v.getUndo().getId(), v.getChanges(), v.getUndo().getSessionId());
                                    }
                                }
                        );
    }
```

My initial reaction was just to set the retention in the internal topic.

But I noticed that is not using the default config and is marked as a DYNAMIC_TOPIC_CONFIG (in AKHQ). After some research I found comments suggesting not setting these values directly and let Kafka handle retention itself.

I'm trying to understand:

1. What could be causing the topic to not release data despite having a zero count?
2. Is it advisable to manually set the retention for this topic?

Here's a screenshot from AKHQ showing the topic information (I edited topic and consumer group name):

[image: AKHQ Topic details]

[image]

Thank you for any insights or assistance you can provide in resolving this Kafka Streams issue. Any additional information or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you see if the problem occurs (or doesn't occur) when excluding Spring Cloud Stream from the picture? I can't think of anything the binder may do to cause this. But, if the binder can do something to fix this issue, we can certainly do that.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. After reading this [post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/optimizing-kafka-streams-applications/#df0280d9-561e-455e-a393-510fb8386f92) in Confluent blog, it was more clear to me that the issue was related to the implementation. So, I refactored it to get rid of the repartitions.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a permission issue? You need to give correct ACL to Kafka Streams, in particular "delete" permissions on internal topics:

From https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/security.html

```
# Allow Streams to read the input topics:
bin/kafka-acls ... --add --allow-principal User:team1 --operation READ --topic input-topic1 --topic input-topic2

# Allow Streams to write to the output topics:
bin/kafka-acls ... --add --allow-principal User:team1 --operation WRITE --topic output-topic1 --topic output-topic2

# Allow Streams to manage its own internal topics:
bin/kafka-acls ... --add --allow-principal User:team1 --operation READ --operation DELETE --operation WRITE --operation CREATE --resource-pattern-type prefixed --topic team1-streams-app1

# Allow Streams to manage its own consumer groups:
bin/kafka-acls ... --add --allow-principal User:team1 --operation READ --operation DESCRIBE --group team1-streams-app1

# Allow Streams EOS:
bin/kafka-acls ... --add --allow-principal User:team1 --operation WRITE --operation DESCRIBE --transactional-id team1-streams-app1 --resource-pattern-type prefixed
```

The repartition topic is configured with infinite retention to guard agains data loss, in case the application would be offline for a longer period of time (we don't want retention to kick in, and delete unprocessed data).

To actually keep the size of the topic at bay, Kafka Streams periodically issue "delete record" request to the broker to purge old data that was fully processed. This "delete record" request need "delete" permission on the internal topics, and might fail to go through if ACL are not configures correctly, leading to unbounded growth.